# Add multiple rows with bind_param() function

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

So i have this code.

```
while($counter < $i){
$link = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'domaci2');

    $query = 'INSERT INTO utisci VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)';
    $statement = $link->prepare($query);    
    $statement->bind_param("isssis", $id, $grad, $ime, $opis, $ocena, $tagovie[$counter]);

    $statement->execute();

    mysqli_close($link);
    $counter++;
    }
```

The thing i want to do is to add multiple rows to my database in this while loop. As you can see everything stays the same, and the only thing that is changing is $tagovie[$counter] variable which should be different in evey next loop.

But i only got one row saved in my database, the first one exactly. Others are just ignored.

I would like to know is there any way i can do this or modify my code.

Thanks in advance.

I try this code also and it is the same

```
$link = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'domaci2');

    $query = 'INSERT INTO utisci VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)';
    $statement = $link->prepare($query);
    while($counter < $i){
       $statement->bind_param("isssis", $id, $grad, $ime, $opis, $ocena, $tagovie[$counter]);
       $counter++;
        }

    $statement->execute();

    mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: Why do you close your mysql connection inside the loop??

Comment: but i will open it in every next loop ?

Comment: @user3616184 Put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the beginning of the PHP file to print the error.

Comment: you have to connect to the database for only once,so write the connection top of the loop and where these variables are getting defined `$id, $grad, $ime, $opis, $ocena,`

Comment: it is the same where ever i open database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should open and close the database connection outside of the loop. The same applies to the prepare statement, you only need to prepare it once.

Your problem is probably caused by the way you are binding the variables:

```
 $statement->bind_param("isssis", $id, $grad, $ime, $opis, $ocena, $tagovie[$counter]);
                                  ^^^ this would be the problem
```

I would assume that the first column - the ID - has a unique constraint so after the first insert, all subsequent inserts will fail as the ID does not change in the loop.

There also seems to be little point in adding the same rows over and over again with just minor variations, you should take a good look at your table structure and database normalization.

Comment: Actually i would create new $id generation code in every loop. Now it is not primary key it is just a number with no meaning. I want to create a one-to-many like table that is why i have little variations.

Comment: @user3616184 You should add error handling. Add this to the top of your script and post any exceptions you get in your question: `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: @user3616184 By the way, does your table not have a primary key?

Comment: somehow $id was primary key. The report function helped a lot. Thanks man you really fixed my problem